# Tampermonkey script blocked by a CSP error

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy, tampermonkey

I am new to javascript and Tampermonkey. I wanted to add a frame to the Memrise's website. The code is as follows:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Merise
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       k1
// @match        https://app.memrise.com/aprender/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=memrise.com
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    var word = document.getElementsByClassName("sc-1nck79x-5 jPETsr")[0]
    var bdy = document.getElementsByClassName("sc-r1ec2z-1 evBYsl")[0]
    var defl = "https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/" + word.innerHTML
    var fr = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    fr.height = "500px"
    fr.src = defl
    fr.style.maxWidth="90%"
    bdy.appendChild(fr);
})();
```

But the code execution blocked due to the error: Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline ("script-src").

Please let me know how can I fix this if there is any way to do that. Thanks.

Comment: try to do research on the question you are asking and show this reasearch on the question. keep up the good work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [GM_addElement](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_addElement) to circumvent such CSP restrictions:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Merise
// @match        https://app.memrise.com/aprender/*
// @grant        GM_addElement
// ==/UserScript==

var word = document.getElementsByClassName('sc-1nck79x-5 jPETsr')[0].textContent;
var bdy = document.getElementsByClassName('sc-r1ec2z-1 evBYsl')[0];
GM_addElement(bdy, 'iframe', {
  src: 'https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/' + encodeURIComponent(word),
  style: 'width: 90%; height: 500px;',
});
```